# Using GREP to find table tags

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to search through a large directory for any `.html` files that contain any `<table>` tags. The grep command seems to be the most appropriate, but I'm having some trouble nailing down the parameters to pass.

Currently I have: `grep -r -l "^<table>$" /directory_to_search_through`

I used -r to recursively search through all files and -l to print only the file names. However, the current string specification searches exclusively for `<table>`, but I want to do a more comprehensive search that includes any table tags that include ids, classes, etc. Additionally, I want to search through only `.html` files, but specifying the directory as /directory/*.html yields a 'No such file or directory' message. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I urge you to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/895245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this reliably you really need to use a bona fide HTML parser.  If it's xhtml then an XML parser would be fine, too.

You could get a good approximation of your desired results with something like this:

```
find /directory/to/search -name '*.html' | xargs grep -l '<table[ \t>]'
```

That will check all the `.html` files in the directory tree rooted at `/directory/to/search`, identifying those that contain (the beginning of) a `<table>` start tag, anywhere on the line, but it can also identify false positives such the text `<table` inside a CDATA section (if in fact the file contains XHTML).

Answer (score 0):

As you have already discovered, grep is not the ideal tool for the job. If your input is well-formed XHTML, you could use an XML parser such as xmlstarlet:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m //table -f -o " table id:" -v "@id" -o " class:" -v "@class" -n *.html
```

This simply selects all `<table>` elements and extracts their id, class and the name of the file that they were found in.

For example:

```
$ cat file.html
<html>
<body>
<table id="abc" class="something">
</table>
</body>
</html>
$ cat file2.html
<html>
<body>
<table id="def" class="something-else">
</table>
</body>
</html>
$ xmlstarlet sel -t -m //table -f -o " table id:" -v "@id" -o " class:" -v "@class" -n *.html
file.html table id:abc class:something
file2.html table id:def class:something-else
```